# How to pass data from module to middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I have a path that should change if I pass a context to the module if not, it defaults to 'api/matrix/version.' The problem is that a global prefix 'api' is set for applications, and I need to replace it specifically for one path only if a value is passed to the module. In this case, I will catch the specific request path in the middleware and process it.

**matrix.module.ts**

```
import { DynamicModule, MiddlewareConsumer, Module, RequestMethod } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MatrixService } from "./services/matrix.service";
import { MatrixMiddleware } from "./middleware/matrix-middleware";

@Module({
    providers: [MatrixService],
    exports: [MatrixService],
})

export class MatrixModule {
    public static path: string;
    static forRoot(context?: string): DynamicModule {
        MatrixModule.path = context ? `${context}/matrix/version` : '/matrix/version';
        return {
            module: MatrixModule,
            providers: [MatrixService],
            exports: [MatrixService],
            global: true,
            imports: [],
        };
    }

    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(MatrixMiddleware).forRoutes({
            path: "*",
            method: RequestMethod.GET,
        });
    }
}
```

**matrix-middleware.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { MatrixService } from '../services/matrix.service';

@Injectable()
export class MatrixMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(private readonly matrixService: MatrixService) {}

    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        if (req.path === this.path) {
            const appVersion = this.matrixService.getVersion();
            res.status(200).json({version: appVersion});
        } else {
            next();
        }
        
    }
}
```

I tried to use forRoutes but it adds everything to 'api', I also saw articles that you should use with() but this is no longer supported.